# VNC desktop only change size of screen not resolution

Tags: 14.04, vnc

Im using Ubuntu 14.04 TLS, vnc4server and from my laptop real vnc
Everything works fine, except resolution, i can change from 800x600 to 1440x900 and the only change i see is the size of the screen, the size of the fonts, icons, etc, continue the same. Its very uncomfortable work like that where the text are so big that i cant program anything there.
Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `xrandr --fb 1440x900` -- works for me (this change is not persistent, though).

Answer (score 0):

```
vnc4server :1 -geometry 1440x900 -depth 32
```

start vncserver by this